Why does my Delaunay Triangulation using the Bowyer Watson algorithm not work?
I am implementing delaunay triangulation on a random set generated points, making use of the Bowyer Watson algorithm.
I seem to be running into a issue where the output seems to be generating way too many triangles that all overlap.
My output drawn from the triangulation made from a random set of points
My attempt at the algorithm is below.
void Delaunay::BowyerWatson(const std::vector<glm::vec2>& _points) {
    glm::vec2 p1(-1000, -1000), p2(1000, -1000), p3(0, 1000);  // Large super triangle
    Triangle superTriangle(p1, p2, p3);
    m_triangles.push_back(superTriangle);

    for (const auto& point : _points) {
        std::vector<Edge> polygonEdges;

        // Identify and remove all bad triangles
        auto it = m_triangles.begin();
        while (it != m_triangles.end()) {
            if (it->circumcircleContains(point)) {
                Edge edges[3] = {
                    {it->vertices[0], it->vertices[1]},
                    {it->vertices[1], it->vertices[2]},
                    {it->vertices[2], it->vertices[0]}
                };
                for (const Edge& edge : edges) {
                    polygonEdges.push_back(edge);  // Collect edges of bad triangles
                }
                it = m_triangles.erase(it);  // Remove bad triangle
            }
            else {
                ++it;
            }
        }

        // Remove duplicate edges
        std::sort(polygonEdges.begin(), polygonEdges.end());
        polygonEdges.erase(std::unique(polygonEdges.begin(), polygonEdges.end(),
            [](const Edge& a, const Edge& b) {
                return (a == b) || (a.m_start == b.m_end && a.m_end == b.m_start);
            }), polygonEdges.end());

        // Re-triangulate the polygonal hole
        for (const Edge& edge : polygonEdges) {
            Triangle newTriangle(edge.m_start, edge.m_end, point);
            m_triangles.push_back(newTriangle);
        }
    }

    // Remove triangles that contain vertices of the super triangle
    m_triangles.erase(std::remove_if(m_triangles.begin(), m_triangles.end(),
        [&p1, &p2, &p3](const Triangle& tri) {
            return tri.containsVertex(p1) || tri.containsVertex(p2) || tri.containsVertex(p3);
        }), m_triangles.end());
}

If you would like to see all of my relevant code on this issue you can here
I set up a basic small sample size of set points to test this, and it seems to work as id expect until complexity increases
I have tried reformating and changing calculations in my code in numerous different ways, just looking for guidance on what my issue may be.

Adding (a.m_start == b.m_end && a.m_end == b.m_start) doesn't actually do anything, because you normalise start and end in the constructor of Edge

@Caleth yes! Thank you, I also found this and im not doing the extra check anymore

Aside: I'd use emplace_back rather than push_back when adding things to these vectors, because you are starting with the constructor parameters, not existing objects. I.e. polygonEdges.emplace_back(it->vertices[0], it->vertices[1]);... and m_triangles.emplace_back(edge.m_start, edge.m_end, point);.

@Caleth Thats a good comment to make, that I completely forgot while putting this together, I'll make the change Thanks.

When looking to remove duplicate edges
std::sort(polygonEdges.begin(), polygonEdges.end());
polygonEdges.erase(std::unique(polygonEdges.begin(),
    polygonEdges.end(),
    [](const Edge& a, const Edge& b) {
        return (a == b) || (a.m_start == b.m_end && a.m_end == b.m_start);
}), polygonEdges.end());

This only removes one of the duplicate edges found and leaves an unwanted one. Which later is used to create extra triangles to fill the poly hole.
Here is the fixed code:
std::sort(polygonEdges.begin(), polygonEdges.end());
std::vector<Edge> uniqueEdges;
for (size_t i = 0; i < polygonEdges.size(); ++i) {
  if (i + 1 < polygonEdges.size() && polygonEdges[i] == 
      polygonEdges[i + 1]) 
  {
    ++i;
  }
  else {
    uniqueEdges.push_back(polygonEdges[i]);
  }
}
polygonEdges.swap(uniqueEdges);


erase removes the extra elements after unique moves the wanted ones to the front.

@Caleth This is true, but as i stated it only removes one version of the duplicate.
For example:
[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3] -> [ 1, 2, 3]
Where for this implementation both copies need to be removed.
For example:
[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3] -> [ 2 ]
As stated in the answer, the seond version accomplishes this.

No it doesn't. You don't remove runs of 3 equivalent elements. (or any other odd number > 1)

@Caleth That would be because three triangles can't share the same edge, only two.

You need to remove all copies of edges that are duplicate, not leave unique ones.
polygonEdges.erase(std::remove_if(polygonEdges.begin(), polygonEdges.end(),
    [](const Edge& a) {
        return std::count(polygonEdges.begin(), polygonEdges.end(), a) > 1;
    }), polygonEdges.end());

